# What is the largest number of rocket engines ever successfully used on a single craft as of 2022?

Tags: rockets, engines, engineering

A fully stacked Starship was [rolled to the pad this week for testing](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/06/spacex-making-progress-toward-orbital-starship-test-flight-later-this-year/). The byline caught my eye, though (emphasis mine)

> SpaceX moves a massive rocket with 33 engines to its launch pad for tests
> **No rocket with this many engines has ever successfully launched.**

The "successfully launched" part is a clear nod to the failed [Soviet N1 rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N1_(rocket)), which had 42 engines (30 + 8 + 4) and went 0 for 4 in launch attempts.

What craft currently holds the "most engines successfully launched" record as of now?

Comment: Do attitude control jets count as rocket engines?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Vertical thrust engines only. I know the RCS could technically count, but the number of the engines on the bottom are the ones doing the actual work.

Comment: @OrganicMarble in the spirit of the question I would say no. Engines that provide substantial on-axis thrust. A payload of 50 satellites capable of putting themselves into final orbit doesn't count for 50 either.

Comment: My money is on Falcon Heavy, it has a moderately large number of engines on a moderately large number of simultaneously ignited boosters. There may be single boosters that have more than 9 engines and vehicle designs that have more than three boosters, but I think the combination of 27 engines simultaneously running (28 egnines in total if you count the second stage) is fairly high.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/other-than-then-n-1-30-engines-has-there-been-a-single-stage-of-a-rocket-with

Comment: In short,  if we sre counting side boosters, it would be Falcon Heavy with 27 engines going at once.  If we are counting failed rockets, the Soviet N1 had a first stage with 30.  On a single first stage with no boosters,  The Falcon 9 and thr Electron rocket both have 9.

Comment: @DanHanson Close, but this is counting engines for all stages, not just one.